# How to get table/col stats from BigQuery tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Does BigQuery provides any sql commands for retrieving table cardinality?

For example, some RDBMS providers have sql commands like:

`show table_stats schemaname tablename`

for getting table cardinality.

Also, what about column stats? Like the number of distinct values in a col and MIN, MAX, etc.

I saw that the BigQuery console provides both table and col stats but I wonder whether these info are accessible through SQL statements

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The features you would like to use are more proper for the language, instead of the tool or service itself.

- To get stats about the table. I found the [Getting table metadata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) which explains how to get table metadata for Tables and Columns. Some of the information you will get  when running the queries found in that doc.

For Tables: the name of the dataset that contains the table, the default lifetime, in days and other [Table_Options view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_options_view) results.

For Columns: The name of the project that contains the dataset, the the column's standard SQL data type, if the value is updatable, stored, or hidden. Find more [Results for the Columns view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view).

- To get stats about columns. You can use the [COUNT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct) function, which retrieves a statistical approximation on the unique values in certain columns.

I found this [Community blog](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-countdistinct-field-works-in-google-bigquery/), where they show different examples and ways to get unique values. It even explains how to increase the approximation threshold.

**EDIT**

It seems that BigQuery does not offer a count of unique fields. However, you can always take a look at the `Schema` and `Details` tabs in your BigQuery UI where the Fields' name are shown, including the type and description.

Example from the Public Datasets:

[image: Public Dataset "Crime"]

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for table stats info like table cardinality, which is different from metadata info from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. While it's true that we can run queries like "select count(*)" to get the information, I wonder whether BigQuery has cache any of such info somewhere such that we don't need to calculate on-demand.

Comment: Added info to my answer. I think there is no "cache" or other mechanism to get this information in BigQuery without running an On-demand query.